# Which SE and SD formulae to use for proportional data?

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error, proportion

I am interested in sex ratio variation. I have taken ~200 families and counted the numbers of males and females in each. Hence I have a 'population' sex ratio (one data point: the total numbers of males / total number of individuals sexed) and also a distribution of family sex ratios.

I am trying to analyse the family sex ratio distribution. This is a distribution of proportions (i.e. binary grouped data) - so should I use the σ = sqrt [ P(1 - P) / n ]? I've only ever used σ= σ / sqrt( n )  and I thought (perhaps incorrectly) that per the CLT that this latter formula could be used for any distribution with a large sample size?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. For the distribution of proportions, I'm interested in the mean of the distribution (so I should use the standard error of the mean formulae); only for an actual proportion itsef should I use the other formulae.